# How to configure basic authentication in IIS SMTP Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, smtp, iis-6

I feel like this is a stupid question but:

I have a test environment set up where I need to enable SMTP basic authentication with IIS. I have a Win2k3 r2 server as a DC in its own windows domain called testdom.local. I also have the MS pop3 server set up with the testdom.local domain on that server. I have a windows account called "simon" on that domain and a mail box set up on the pop3 service.

With anonymous access set up on the IIS smtp server, I can send an email from a client to the server which will arrive in the simon mailbox. If I turn on basic authentication on the SMTP server, I can not get the mail client (outlook 2003) to authenticate.

I have followed what is said here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324285

I have tried:

- the domains "testdom" and "testdom.local" in the default domain box
  in the SMTP authentication properties.
- Using the logon names "simon", "simon@testdom.local" and "testdom\simon" in the logon
  properties on the mail client.
- I have tried specifying smtp authentication using "use same settings as my incoming server" and manually specifying the account details.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I am missing something really obvious!

Please note:
This is a test environment, I have a requirement to use SMTP basic auth, so I am not interested in using any other authentication option.
I have made sure Integrated Windows and SPA auth are turned off on client and server, and I have double checked the password is right because the pop3 works to collect the mail.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and the issue turned out to be that I was trying to authenticate using the Administrator account. As soon as I tried a non-administrative user account it started working perfectly.

Possibly related information: http://www.apijunkie.com/APIJunkie/blog/post/2007/11/SMTP-535-573-Authentication-unsuccessful-error-on-Exchange-server-2003.aspx

That page no longer exists. Its content, using the Way Back Machine is copied here for reference:

> If you receive this error and have exhausted all other recommended
>   options from Microsoft and other sources on the web then you might
>   have stumbled upon the same unknown exchange feature/bug that we
>   suffered from.
>
> After doing some digging around it seemed that when we installed
>   exchange it did not set permissions properly on some of the existing
>   users. So some users could not authenticate against the SMTP server
>   even though it seemed like they had the exact same permissions and
>   SMTP settings as other users that could authenticate.
>
> To solve the problem we had to create new user accounts. New user
>   accounts did not receive the same SMTP error.
>
> To test if you suffer from the same problem just try to create a new
>   domain user account and assign an exchange profile/email address to
>   it. If this user is able to authenticate through SMTP then you found
>   your culprit.