# Windows Smtp Server administrator login

Tags: windows, smtp

I newly setup Windows SMTP Server on Windows Server 2012 R2.
Any account exception Administrator can send email.
But in the case of Administrator account, mail server said "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful".

I think there are some restriction for Administrator account.
Other account works perfectly.
Is there any tip for using Administrator account for sending email?

Thanks

Ref.
[How to configure basic authentication in IIS SMTP Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/323349/how-to-configure-basic-authentication-in-iis-smtp-server)

Comment: Workgroup or a domain? Local or domain account? Please provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: I didn't use AD and tested in local account.

Comment: Any account except administrator works property.